# Настройка OpenVPN для сервера/клиента

Tags: teamviewer, ssh, ubuntu, openvpn

Привет всем!)

В общем, есть домашний комп (Win8), есть рабочий комп (Ubuntu 12.04)

Надо настроить удалённый доступ с домашнего на рабочий комп.

Вопросы:

1) Что в данном случае считать сервером, а что клиентом? Я иду по инструкции с Хабра http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/58689/

2) На работе выдали электронные сертификаты и ключи .csr, .crt, .key. В инструкции написано, что ключи и сертификаты надо генерировать как для клиента, так и для сервера самостоятельно. В моём случае выданные ключи являются клиентскими? или серверными?

3) Через какую программу (может быть, встроенную в Win8) можно так сказать увидеть свой удалённый рабочий стол?

Спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

почему эти вопросы незадать тому, кто выдал ключи.

1. Конечно каждый комп (и Win8, и Ubuntu 12.04) - клиент.
2. Тут вы наверное совместили выданные ключи и инструкцию с хабра. Не надо так. Запросите инструкцию от того источника, что выдал ключи.
3. Используйте нативный клиент от производителя http://openvpn.net/ для создания сетевого подключения, для ubuntu это выглядит так:

   sudo apt-get install openvpn

после этого вы становитесь участником вашей локальной сети и можете всё (обычно это так), что можете с другого компьютера в вашей корпоративной сети.

после этого необходимо поправить /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf в соответствии с инструкцией от того же источника.Для доступа на "рабочий стол" необходимо почитать про [Rdesktop](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdesktop) и про [VNC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).